# Socket em Java não está imprimindo o que deveria

Tags: java, socket

Servidor:

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            String s = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("> "+s);
```

Esse simples código está retornando a seguinte saída:

[image: Problema]

Como fazer para ele não mostrar esses quadradinho na saída, e sim mostrar o conteúdo a mensagem (quinta linha do console)?

Código completo:

```
package com.estilosoft.servidor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Servidor {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String clientSentence;
    String capitalized;
    ServerSocket socket = null;

    try {

        // Cria um SocketServer (Socket característico de um servidor)
        socket = new ServerSocket(6831);
        System.out.println("abriu");

        while(true) {    
            Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
            System.out.println("Con "+ connectionSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Iniciou");
            String s = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Acabou");
            System.out.println("> "+s);


        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("fechou");
    }  
}


}
```

Comment: O que está sendo enviado para o servidor?

Comment: Então @bfavaretto eu não sei ao certo o que está sendo enviado, pelo o que parece não é um texto simples e sim um arquivo ou algo do tipo. (Eu não tenho muitas informações do cliente).

Comment: Você pode postar o código ao invés de postar uma imagem? Precisamos saber o que o cliente está enviando.

Comment: @avelino fiz a atualização da publicação com a class servidor, ainda não tenho muita coisa implementada, além de ser inciante não sei ao certo o que está sendo enviado para o servidor, essa é a minha missão, descobrir o que está sendo enviado. kkk   (Fiz um sniffer na rede e parece ser um arquivo xml, não é certeza)

Comment: Geralmente (digo porque seu uso parece ser incomum), o servidor e o cliente precisam ter algum tipo de contrato: ou o servidor sabe o que espera receber, ou o cliente avisa o que vai enviar. Sem saber de nada disso, tudo são bytes, e os mesmos bytes podem ser interpretados de diferentes maneiras. Você vai precisar de montes de testes e inferências para descobrir o que está sendo enviado.